# Using python to analyze a FITS image for a star count

Tags: python, fits

I have several FITS images taken with my telescope and I need help with a python code to analyze the images and obtain a star count for each image. I don't have any code yet because I'm extremely new to python. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.astropython.org/tutorial/2010/10/PyFITS-FITS-files-in-Python

Comment: This sort of question is too broad for Stack Overflow, which is meant to address questions about actual problems in existing code.  A better place to ask might be the AstroPy mailing list, where people discuss this sort of thing: http://mail.scipy.org/mailman/listinfo/astropy

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how helpful it can be, but the good starting point is
[Astropy Docs](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/index.html#introduction).

But I think you can just use [imstar](http://tdc-www.harvard.edu/wcstools/imstar/)